# Using HtmlAgilityPack to get specific data in C# and serialize it to json

Tags: c#, html, json, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

I've downloaded an html source code and I'm trying to get some data out of it to serialize it to a "json" file.

This is the html source file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzweTZsfeoxMTWk2LVdnYTJMRUE/view?usp=sharing

In the html code there are "2" groups that I wish to collect data from.

At the moment I managed to get the code inside this "2" groups and display it in two panels using labels. My code is as fallows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Parser_Test_1._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"C:...\bin\Debug\xbFrSourceCode.txt");

            string datacollected1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"favoritesContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul")[0].InnerHtml;
            string datacollected2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"friendsContent\"]/div[2]/div[2]")[0].InnerHtml;
            label1.Text = datacollected1;
            label2.Text = datacollected2;
        }      

    }
}
```

From this two groups I wish to collect the users in them and for each user, their respective data to serialize it unto a json file.

Each user is separated with `<li ...></li>`

For each user I wish to get:

- Gamertag: `data-gamertag="this is the gamertag"`
- Gamerpic: it's in `class="gamerpicWrapper"` the `src="this is the gamerpic"`
- Realname:  `<div class="realName">this is the realname</div>`
- PrimaryInfo: `<div class="primaryInfo">this is the primaryinfo</div>`
- isOnline: `<div class="statusIcon">` if there is code here, then in the json file this value will be true `</div>`

This is an example of the desired "json" file format (Note that the fallowing code is probably badly written.):

```
{
    "favorites" : 
    [
        {
            "gamertag" : "Gamertag1",
            "gamerpic" : "gamerpicURL",
            "realname" : "",
            "primaryInfo" : "",
            "isOnline" : false,
        },
        {
            "gamertag" : "Gamertag2",
            "gamerpic" : "gamerpicURL",
            "realname" : "realname2",
            "primaryInfo" : "primaryinfo2",
            "isOnline" : true,
        },
        {
            "gamertag" : "Gamertag3",
            "gamerpic" : "gamerpicURL",
            "realname" : "",
            "primaryInfo" : "",
            "isOnline" : false,
        },
        {
            "gamertag" : "Gamertag4",
            "gamerpic" : "gamerpicURL",
            "realname" : "realname4",
            "primaryInfo" : "",
            "isOnline" : true,
        }

    ]
    "friends" : 
    [
        {
            "gamertag" : "Gamertag1",
            "gamerpic" : "gamerpicURL",
            "realname" : "",
            "primaryInfo" : "",
            "isOnline" : true,
        },
        {
            "gamertag" : "Gamertag2",
            "gamerpic" : "gamerpicURL",
            "realname" : "realname2",
            "primaryInfo" : "primaryinfo2",
            "isOnline" : false,
        },
        {
            "gamertag" : "Gamertag3",
            "gamerpic" : "gamerpicURL",
            "realname" : "realname3",
            "primaryInfo" : "",
            "isOnline" : true,
        },
        {
            "gamertag" : "Gamertag4",
            "gamerpic" : "gamerpicURL",
            "realname" : "",
            "primaryInfo" : "",
            "isOnline" : false,
        }

    ]
}
```

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could show me how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive criticism. I've been attracted to coding most of my life, but recently I've decided to deeply experiment with it. I decided to start by learning C#. To learn this language I decided to work on a project and learn the language trying to create and finish this project. At the moment I posted this question I was starting this project. I already figured out how to do what I'm asking for in this question. And to answer your question, yes. Originally I got the xpaths from chrome. Though I didn't know how to express and write the xpaths manually, I do know now.

Comment: Well. You need to know xpath in order to proceed. I will help you this time. Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) while I produce some code for you.

Comment: Remember to mark the correct answer or at least comment on it if it helped you it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows an appropriate usage of xpath and HAP. The usage of xpath can be simplified, but you gave me a 4k html files and I don't feel like learning the structure of all of it. However the code gets everything you want as variables. Now it is your job to put into a json structure - but if you don't have any knowledge of JSON then consider using XML.

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        doc.Load("damn.html");

        //First off we find the nodes we want to collect data from. Note that we are only looking for a singlenode compared to your code where you find all nodes
        //this could be cut down to selectnodes where we take all <li> tages with each div tag. But for simplicity.
        HtmlNodeCollection favoritesContent = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='favoritesContent']/div[@class='personListWrapper']/div[@class='gamerList']/ul//li");

        foreach (HtmlNode x in favoritesContent)
        {
            //here we find the gamertag which is an attribute in <li> if <li> does not have that value
            //it will then return the deault value ""(empty string as specified)
            string gamerTag = x.GetAttributeValue("data-gamertag", "");
            HtmlNode temp = x.SelectSingleNode("./a[@class='gamerpicWrapper']/*/img[@class='favorite']");
            string srcOnPic = temp.GetAttributeValue("src", "not found");
            string realName = x.SelectSingleNode("./descendant::*//div[@class='realName']").InnerText;
            string primaryInfo = x.SelectSingleNode("./descendant::*//div[@class='primaryInfo']").InnerText;

            if (0 < x.SelectSingleNode("./div[@class='statusIcon']").InnerHtml.Length)
            {
                bool online = true;

            }
        }
```