# Serializing "string list" to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, serialization, visual-studio-2015

## **(I'v restated my question here: [Creating class instances based on dynamic item lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782580/creating-class-instances-based-on-dynamic-item-lists/35782803#35782803))**

I'm currently working on a program in Visual Studio 2015 with C#.

I have 5 list strings that contain data that I wish to serialize to a json file.

```
public List<string> name { get; private set; }
public List<string> userImageURL { get; private set; }
public List<string> nickname { get; private set; }
public List<string> info { get; private set; }
public List<string> available { get; private set; }
```

An example of the desired json file format is the fallowing:

```
{
    "users" : 
    [
        {
            "name" : "name1",
            "userImageURL" : "userImageURL1",
            "nickname" : "nickname1",
            "info" : "info1",
            "available" : false,
        },
        {
            "name" : "name2",
            "userImageURL" : "userImageURL2",
            "nickname" : "nickname2",
            "info" : "info2",
            "available" : false,
        },
        {
            "name" : "name3",
            "userImageURL" : "userImageURL3",
            "nickname" : "nickname3",
            "info" : "info3",
            "available" : false,
        },
        {
            "name" : "name4",
            "userImageURL" : "userImageURL4",
            "nickname" : "nickname4",
            "info" : "info4",
            "available" : false,
        }

    ]
}
```

Note that there might be errors in the json example above.

I've tried combining the 5 lists to create 1 list to serialize it using the following code:

```
users = new List<string>(name.Count + userImageURL.Count + nickname.Count + info.Count + available.Count);
            allPlayers.AddRange(name);
            allPlayers.AddRange(userImageURL);
            allPlayers.AddRange(nickname);
            allPlayers.AddRange(info);
            allPlayers.AddRange(available);
```

Then I serialize the list with the fallowing code:

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
            File.WriteAllText("data.json", data);
```

This just creates an array of unorganized objects. I wish to know how can I organize them as expressed in the format above.

PS: I'm pretty new to coding as you can tell. Sorry if I'm not expressing the question correctly or using the right terminology. Also, this is not the original code. The code creates this lists which I wish to serialize into a json file.

PSS: This data is collected using HtmlAgilityPack. I asked a question yesterday asking how could I parse an html file and serialize it's data to a json file. [Using HtmlAgilityPack to get specific data in C# and serialize it to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693367/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-specific-data-in-c-sharp-and-serialize-it-to-json) . As nobody answered, I decided to try and do it myself. The method that I used may not be the best, but it is what I could do with the knowledge that I have.

Comment: Your properties would not create that output anyway. You need to create a user class and make a List of that. Not a list of each property.

Comment: You "do not" have to write with "quote marks" everywhere. That's not the normal way to write, you will be understood more easily if you write more correctly.

Comment: I'm a bit impressed that my question is getting down voted so much. I tried to simplify my question because I wasn't sure if people we're not answering my other questions because they we're to long.

Comment: Not sure if any of you could help me out now, but I've restated my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782580/creating-class-instances-based-on-dynamic-item-lists/35782803#35782803

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest refactoring your code to start with - instead of having 5 ["parallel collections"](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/), have a *single* collection of a new type, `User`:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
}

...

// In your containing type
public List<User> Users { get; set; }
```

This is likely to make life simpler not just for your JSON, but for the rest of the code too - because you no longer have the possibility of having more nicknames than image URLs, etc. In general, having multiple collections that must be kept in sync with each other is an antipattern. There *are* times where it's appropriate - typically providing different efficient ways of retrieving the same data - but for something like this it's best avoided.

Comment: @JoseCancel: The answer is still the same - you should restructure your data, as early as possible. You can do that even if you start off with five separate lists.

Comment: This data is collected using HtmlAgilityPack. I asked a question yesterday asking how could I parse an html file and serialize it's data to a json file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693367/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-specific-data-in-c-sharp-and-serialize-it-to-json . As nobody answered, I decided to try and do it myself. The method that I used may not be the best, but it is what I could do with the knowledge that I have.

Comment: I managed to collect the desired data and now I'm facing the task of serializing it to a json file. If you could help me out with this please do so. If you know of a better method please share also.

Comment: @JoseCancel: Well if you have a root object with a property called `Users` of type `List<User>` and you use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root)` then it should just work. Use `[JsonProperty]` to adjust the names used in the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll research about [JsonProperty].

Comment: Not sure if you could help me out now, but I've restated my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782580/creating-class-instances-based-on-dynamic-item-lists/35782803#35782803

Answer (score 0):

It is actually what Jon says, but to move from your parallel lists to Jon's single list you need something like (assuming all lists have the same number of elements in the same order):

```
Users = new List<User>();
for (var i = 0; i < name.Count; i++)
{
    Users.Add(new User
    {
        Available = available[i],
        ImageUrl = userImageURL[i],
        Info = info[i],
        Name = name[i],
        NickName = nickname[i]
    });
}
```

And then serialise the Users list.